# How can I see all the available methods in a $request and its children methods with vscode?

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code

With **VSCode**, how can I see all the available methods like `token()` in

```
$request->user()
```

or `delete()` in:

```
$request->user()->token()
```

?

I'm currently using this:

```
    Log::info(get_class($request->user()));
    Log::info(get_class_methods('App\Models\User'));
    Log::info(get_class($request->user()->token()));
    Log::info(get_class_methods('Laravel\Passport\Token'));
```

But there may be some better solution.

Comment: Are you asking about code intelligence, or using dumps/logging?

Comment: I use the intelephense plugin and it does a pretty good job, you can also check out https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper